# what frameworks or libraries required for making chat messenger ios

Tags: ios, xcode, chat

I want to ask which frameworks and libraries required for making chat messenger in IOS with json like whatsapp.I want to make chat messenger.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the back-end server technology. Currently, my company uses a popular protocol called [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/), which has many [server-side](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/) and [client-side](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) implementations. To develop XMPP based apps for iOS, you can use [xmppframework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).